# Count number of times a string is printed

Tags: java

I have a for loop that prints a string multiple times.

I need to know:

How do I get the number of times the string is printed?

Thanks!

Comment: Use a counter variable?

Comment: Please give more detail. There isn't *nearly* enough information here. Read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: The same number of times you iterate the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int count = 0

for (int i = 0 ; i < stop_criteria; i++){
    // print string
    count++;
}
printf("Number of times printed %d", count);
```

or as  [TheLostMind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2193767/thelostmind) suggest:

```
int i;
for (i = 0 ; i < stop_criteria; i++){
    // print string
}

printf("Number of times printed %d", i);
```